# solving the recurrence relation using the fastest method

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

what is the fastest method in solving recurrence relation that we can solve the following recurrence and get the answer $O(\log^3n)$

$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{4})+O(\log^2n)=O(\log^3n)$?

Comment: "He [von Neumann] supposedly had the habit of simply writing answers to homework assignments on the board (the method of solution being, of course, obvious)."

Comment: You misunderstand. The point of the story is that the **fastest** method is to look at the question, immediately see the obvious answer, and then write that down. All other methods require more time.

Comment: The simply easiest method for solving $\,T(n) = T(n/c) + O(f(n))\,$ is to guess that it is $\,O(\log(n)f(n)).\,$ It usually works.

Comment: I came up with this guess that makes intuitive sense to me based on my experience. No lectures, publications, or proofs. I guess certain assumptions are needed for it to hold.

Comment: You would probably be interested in the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), which provides a way to (at a glance) solve recurrences of the type you've mentioned.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph -- In the linked wikipedia article, this problem falls into case 2a, where $c_\text{crit} = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE!

You might be interested in the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form), which gives a quick way to determine the asymptotics of many recurrences of the type you're interested in.

In particular, your question falls into case $2a$ of the linked wikipedia article with $c_\text{crit} = \log_4(1) = 0$.

Then $f = O(n^0 \log^2(n))$, so by the master theorem $T = O(\log^{2+1}(n))$, as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph -- $a = 1$. We consider case 2a.... I guess by pattern matching? Here $f = \log^2(n) = n^0 \log^2(n)$. Which is what case 2a handles.